# Computer is typing forward slash ( / ) automatically

Tags: linux, windows-10, keyboard, hardware-failure, lubuntu

I am facing a very strange issue with my HP laptop. The problem is that forward slash is getting typed automatically by the computer.

It started yesterday when I was writing a document and streams of forward slashes began to fill my document. I tried to search up the problem but forward slashes filled up the search bar of my browser ( Firefox ). I closed my laptop and started it again and the problem was gone ! But after working for like 1.5 hours, it started happening again.

OS on which this problem occurred was LUBUNTU 20.04.

But this is not really related to OS as I am having two OS's, LUBUNTU and Windows 10 Home, and the problem persists on both of them.

I booted my laptop to Windows 10 and forward slashes filled the password field on the log in screen. Somehow I removed them and logged into Windows. Problem didn't occurred in the entirety of that session. But in my next session ( on windows itself ), it occurred again randomly.

Someone please help me as it's affecting my work.

TLDR :

- Forward slashes are getting typed automatically.
- In Windows, it happens only on the Log in screen and sometimes while working.
- But in Linux ( Lubuntu 20.04 ), it happens anytime randomly
- Disappears for sometime after rebooting the system.

Comment: Seems like a keyboard hardware problem.

Comment: @choroba if it's a hardware problem then why it's happening randomly ( not truly random cause it happens mostly after 1-2 hours of activity )

Comment: Probably electrical "noise" affecting the keyboard.  This could be from somewhere inside the keyboard, or from a nearby device (eg, printer), or even from the utility power.

Comment: You can try this: 1. Turn off the laptop

2. Remove AC power if plugged.

3. press and Hold Power button for more than 60 seconds.

4. Then, Start the Laptop as Usual. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Keyboard-stops-working/td-p/6278283

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a keyboard issue rather than an issue pertaining to an Operating System. I would recommend you to check for errors in the keys of your keyboard using a website such as [Keyboard Tester](http://keyboardtester.com). Launch the tester in the website and try clicking each key (or just the faulty key 1-2 times). Wait some time and if the key is at fault, it'll start clicking automatically and you will hear a clicking sound in the keyboard tester webpage.

The only way to fix this issue is to replace the faulty keyboard/key. However, if you are not in a position to replace the keyboard right away, you can disable the key (here: forward slash) functionality using tools like [Disable Key](https://disable-key.en.softonic.com).

This tool helps you *disable any key on your keyboard; customizing it to your specific needs. Select from the different modes available on Disable Key for tasks such as Program, Schedule and Always. With Program mode you select any application on your system and this tool will automatically disable your specified key anytime the application is running. You can select specific times and dates for your key deactivations with Schedule mode, and Always mode allows you to disable any key for as long as you want.*

Also, if you want to remap (assign the functionality of the key that is giving error to some other key on the keyboard), [KeyTweak](https://keytweak.en.softonic.com) will help you out. Not just remapping the key functionality, this freeware is also capable of disabling key functionalities.

If you try any of the given fix, do let me know how it does :)

Comment: Keyboard tester is working fine ( but I wasn't getting the error in this session anyways ). The thing is that it happens randomly e.g. computer is working fine at this moment but will go berserk after sometime ( maybe ), when it happens I don't have much choices as wherever there is an input field ( like browsers search bar, notepad etc. ), '/' starts printing. Also if it's a keyboard issue then why it's happening randomly and not all the times ? and in Windows it happens mostly on the Log-In screen ( the screen where we type password to open the computer ).

Comment: That's certainly a keyboard problem. There are lot of mechanical components involved. Just replace the keyboard and you'll see the difference.

Comment: ok will try that n see